# Update ListView DataTemplate after removing one row

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I'm facing an unexpected situation while working with ListView. I've this ListView with rows having a backgroung color according to its parity. It works quite good until I remove an element from the binded collection, and then two rows with the same background color appears together. Here's my code:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="EvenIndexDataTemplate">
      <ViewCell>
          <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray"">
                <!-- my content here -->
          </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="OddIndexDataTemplate">
      <ViewCell>
          <Grid BackgroundColor="White"">
                <!-- my content here -->
          </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>

  <datatemp:EvenOddTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplate"
                                    EvenTemplate="{StaticResource EvenIndexDataTemplate}"
                                    OddTemplate="{StaticResource OddIndexDataTemplate}" />
</ResourceDictionary>



<ContentPage.Content>

    <!-- something here -->

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateResource}" />

    <!-- something else here -->

</ContentPage.Content>
```

My DataTemplateSelector class:

```
public class EvenOddTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EvenTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate OddTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var itemsView = (ListView)container;
        return ((IList)itemsView.ItemsSource).IndexOf(item) % 2 == 0 ? EvenTemplate : OddTemplate;
    }
```

What I want to get is to keep adjacents rows with different background color after removing an item. At this point ItemsSource gets modified only by Adding/Removing. I've not tried to insert an item. I don't need it for this feature I'm working on.

Any idea?

[Quick Demo](https://github.com/saimel/ListViewTemplate)

Comment: assign `ItemsSource = null`, then set it back to your collection - this should force a refresh

Comment: that will clear the list view and will add all elements again one by one, not a good UX

Comment: @SaimelSaez According to your description, I think you may only have to load the ListView, so that you can select the datatemplate again.

Comment: `ItemsSource` should be `ObservableCollection` to reflect changes automatically , otherwise(if it is a `List`) you will have to reassign `ListView.ItemsSource` every time there is a change in list

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT when you say `load the ListView` do you mean `create a new instance`? If that's the case then ain't gonna have a good UX.

Comment: @Morse of course I'm using `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: I just shared a [Quick Demo](https://github.com/saimel/ListViewTemplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue. Here's what I did:

I created a customization of `ViewCell` class and added three bindable properties `ContainerItemsSource`, `EvenBackgroundColor` and `OddBackgroundColor`, then I override `OnBindingContextChanged()` to make sure to set `View` background color by its index within the collection.

You can check it out on this [new brach](https://github.com/saimel/ListViewTemplate/tree/feature/even-odd-cell) on github repo.

Basically the idea is to use it on this way:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YOUR_ITEMS_SOURCE}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:EvenOddCell ContainerItemsSource="{Binding YOUR_ITEMS_SOURCE, 
                                     Source={x:Reference YOUR_PAGE_BINDING_CONTEXT}}" 
                               EvenBackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                               OddBackgroundColor="White">

                <!-- YOUR CELL CONTENT -->

            </local:EvenOddCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My custom `EvenOddCell`:

```
public class EvenOddCell : ViewCell
{
    public Color EvenBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(EvenBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(EvenBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }

    public Color OddBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(OddBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(OddBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }

    public IList ContainerItemsSource
    {
        get => (IList)GetValue(ContainerItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContainerItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty EvenBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(EvenBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(EvenOddCell), default(Color));

    public static BindableProperty OddBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(OddBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(EvenOddCell), default(Color));

    public static BindableProperty ContainerItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ContainerItemsSource), typeof(IList), typeof(EvenOddCell),
        default(IList), propertyChanged: OnContainerItemsSourcePropertyChanged);

    private static void OnContainerItemsSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue != null && newValue is INotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)newValue).CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    ((EvenOddCell)bindable).OnBindingContextChanged();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        if (BindingContext != null && ContainerItemsSource is IList)
        {
            var idx = ContainerItemsSource.IndexOf(BindingContext);
            View.BackgroundColor = idx % 2 == 0 ? EvenBackgroundColor : OddBackgroundColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gload to hear that you have solved your problem, please remember to mark your reply as answer,  it is helpful to others to find this answer, thanks.